# Is it best to use GIF images or do CSS animation with multiple images?

Tags: angular, css-animations, animated-gif

I have a simple question **Is it best to use GIF images or do CSS animation with multiple images?**

Which will have high performance?
Which will be more responsive compared to both?

What are the pros & cons?

Open to other options too, other than the GIF & animates images...

Comment: GIFs are limited to 256 colors per frame or even per image

Answer (score 0):

There are pros and cons for both options

**GIF pros**

- supported by all browsers
- easier to use (just an `<img />` element)

**GIF cons**

- low color palette
- less flexibility (it is what it is, if you want to change the animation you have to update the whole image)

**CSS animation pros**

- lightweight, faster loading time
- more versatility and options

**CSS animation cons**

- learning curve
- not SEO friendly
- not all animations are supported by all browsers